# how to show the code in html view in php?

Tags: php, html

I have some code like below

```
 <?php $pageid = $_GET['pageid']; ?>
                            <?php $gettitlecontent =  mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select id, title,content from pages where id = '".$pageid."'")); ?>
                            <h4><?php echo $gettitlecontent['title']; ?></h4>
                            <p><?php echo strip_tags($gettitlecontent['content']); ?></p>
```

While print this i have output like this

```
<?php echo strip_tags($gettitlecontent['content']); ?>



 <p><a href="../../../n/html/history.php?p_lang=english" target="_blank">With 141 elegant a</a>nd luxurious guest rooms and suites in an incomparable setting, Ree Hotel Siem Reap encapsulates the opulent yet accessible top-end accommodation that today's discerning international clientele expects. Unparalleled levels of service and unmatched facilities make Ree Hotel Siem Reap the only choice for discerning travelers looking to explore the unforgettable ancient ruins of Angkor from a refined haven of in
```

its shows as the code vie. how can i convert this one to html view in php ?

**Expected output**

With 141 elegant and luxurious guest rooms and suites in an incomparable setting, Ree Hotel Siem Reap encapsulates the opulent yet accessible top-end accommodation that today's discerning international clientele expects. Unparalleled levels of service and unmatched facilities make Ree Hotel Siem Reap the only choice for discerning travelers looking to explore the unforgettable ancient ruins of Angkor from a refined haven of in

Comment: Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: You need to set up your webserver to interpret the PHP, and then view it in a browser. For either you don't give enough information to really help you.